# rails3 is not adding the 2nd id to my table

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, routes, foreign-keys, models, nested

the problem I'm having is company_id is not been save to the details table
I know the company_id is there I check it using <%= debug(params[:id])%> on the form before adding all company details information  but for some reason is saving everything else but the company_id

```
##user.rb
has_one :company

##company.rb
belongs_to :user
has_one :detail

##detail.rb
belongs_to :user

##details controller
 def new
    @detail = Detail.new
    user_id = session[:user_id]
    company_id = params[:id]

  end

  def create     
    @detail = Detail.new(params[:detail])
    @detail.user_id = session[:user_id]
    @detail.company_id = params[:id]
  end

###settings.html.erb
### this is where i make sure that company_id gets pass with the url

  link_to 'New Detail', {:controller => 'details', :action =>'new', :id => company.id }, :class => 'plus'

#####routes
    resources :details
    resources :companies
    resources :users
    resources :sessions
```

I know this may not look pretty or proper if you know a better way please let me know...thanks in advance.

Comment: Please post the form that is rendered by your new method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I didn't realize this until later but I need it pass values to from on the view to the from like so

```
  <% @companies.each do |company| %>
      <%= link_to 'New Detail', {:controller =>'details', :action => 'new', :company_id => company.id},  :class => 'plus' %>
    <% end %>
```

and I need it to collect that value on the from...like so

```
<%= form_for(:detail, :url =>{:action => 'create', :company_id => @company.id}) do |f| %>
...(values)
<% end %>
```

Answer (score 0):

I notice something immediately. You may need to fix your associations first. Assuming, a user has one company and a company has one detail.

```
##user.rb
has_one :company

##company.rb
belongs_to :user
has_one :detail

##detail.rb
belongs_to :user
```

Should be:

```
##user.rb
has_one :company

##company.rb
belongs_to :user
has_one :detail

##detail.rb
belongs_to :company
```

Although, depending on your domain requirements. I would normally have it as: User has_many Companies. And since details is 1:1 with company, I would include all the details inside company.

Comment: I fix that but still is not add the foreign key on the table